How to get using Kirchoff diffraction integral formula
I am unsure about the results, but is it possible to generate diffraction pattern like following in the second picture. The following equation is like this added in the first picture for different wavelengths. The graph are plotted in the picture as Intensity vs Radial position in the far field (r).  


Please post the forumla as Mathematica code.
